# Scrollview not working with viewpager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-nestedscrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
tools:context="com.app.trainingapp.home.activity.ProductInfoDetail">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_product_detail" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/detail_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/appBar"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/top_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/product_detail_top_height"
                        android:padding="@dimen/product_image_padding"
                        android:src="@drawable/product" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/product_detail_top_height"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                    <com.app.trainingapp.customviews.TypefacedTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:text="@string/dummy_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/faint_black"
                        app:customTypeface="RalewayRegular" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/top_container"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/view_margin_left"
                android:background="@color/view_color_grey" />

            <com.app.trainingapp.customviews.TypefacedTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_medication"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/separator"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_10"
                android:text="@string/str_medication"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_medication"
                app:customTypeface="RalewayBold" />

            <com.app.trainingapp.utils.FlowLayout
                android:id="@+id/flow_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txt_medication"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_10"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/flow_item_horizaontal_spacing"
                app:orientation="horizontal"
                app:verticalSpacing="@dimen/flow_item_vertical_spacing" />

            <com.app.trainingapp.customviews.CustomViewPager
                android:id="@+id/medication_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/flow_container"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_10">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/medication_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_layout_height"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:background="@drawable/tablayout_line"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_selector_color"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
                <!--<View-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="0.5dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_below="@id/medication_tabs"-->
                <!--android:background="@color/view_color_grey" />-->

            </com.app.trainingapp.customviews.CustomViewPager>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Check the above xml, I have viewpager insite NestedScrollView,
I want to scroll whole page with viewpager?
My problem is when I try to scroll page it's not working and viewpager scrolls internally.
Please let me know if anything is wrong in code.